# HTML5 API javascript library and CSS tools for web/mobile apps

Tags: javascript, api, web-applications, html, mobile-application

Could any one please tell me the best(easy to learn with most functionality and widely used) HTML5 API, javascript library and CSS tools used for mobile/web app development using HTML5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only in alpha at present but have a look at [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You should probabbly have a look at [SenchaTouch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) which did a great job for me.

Answer (score 0):

[html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) is a great set of templates for future proof/reactive design for web/mobile apps.